# Mongodb: Modify all elements in the specified array field using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo-3.x

The following is an example from [Mongodb Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) to explain how to modify all elements in the specified array field.
Consider a collection **test** with the following documents:

`{ "_id" : 1, "grades" : [ 85, 82, 80 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "grades" : [ 88, 90, 92 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "grades" : [ 85, 100, 90 ] }`

To increment all **elements** in the grades array by **10** for all documents in the collection, I tried the all positional `$[]` operator:

`db.test.update_many({}, { "$inc": { "grades.$[]": 10}})`

However I got the following error from pymongo:

`WriteError: cannot use the part (grades of grades.$[]) to traverse the element ({grades: [ 85, 82, 80 ]})`

I also tried `db.test.update_many({}, { "$inc": { "grades.$[]": 10}}, {"multi": "true"})`, just like the one shown in the manual, but got the following error from pymongo:

`TypeError: upsert must be True or False`

I also tried other examples and all got the same error. Any idea why that happened? I am using MongoDB 3.6, so `$[]` is supported.

Comment: Run command `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )` from shell to use array filters.

Comment: @Veeram: You remind me I am using the server from mlab and the server version is 3.4.7. I just tried the code in the local server and it worked. So I need to update the MongoDB server version. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: @JianliCheng if the server is under mLab's control, then they're the only one that is capable of changing your server version. You might want to contact mLab's support to see if this is possible.